# MySQL Ler URL HTTP

Tags: mysql, node.js, windows, url

Gostaria que o mysql lesse uma url através de um `SELECT`

Pesquisei e vi que tem uma resposta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21750226/6754506).

Fiz todo o procedimento conforme está nesse [link](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_str/blob/master/README.win_x86.txt), porém sem sucesso

O select chamaria a url como nesse exemplo [aqui](http://open-bi.blogspot.com/2012/11/call-restful-web-services-from-mysql.html)

```
SELECT http_get('<url>');
SELECT http_post('<url>', '<data>');
SELECT http_put('<url>', '<data>');
SELECT http_delete('<url>');
```

A instalação é para windows

Falta mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Quero que o mysql leia uma url

Comment: As funções foram criadas?http_get(),http_post(),http_put(),http_delete(). Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Não. Não foram criadas